# Android res.getIdentifier() returns zero only when context is wrapped in specific language

Tags: android

In my Activity I have the following line to find the id of a layout I need to inflate:

```
int layoutId = res.getIdentifier("name_of_layout_that_does_exist", "layout", context.getPackageName());
```

This works fine, returning the id of the relevant layout, and everything after works fine... *except when the language for the app is set to Turkish!*  (`tr`)

I set the language to be used for the Activity by way of the following override in the Activity definition:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context baseContext) {
    String appLocale = MyFunctions.getAppLocale(baseContext); // this is "tr"
    super.attachBaseContext(MyContextWrapper.wrap(baseContext, appLocale));
}
```

where `MyContextWrapper` is:

```
public class MyContextWrapper extends ContextWrapper {

    private static final String TAG = "Meteogram_ContextWrappr";

    public MyContextWrapper(Context base) {
        super(base);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static ContextWrapper wrap(Context context, String language) {
        Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
        Locale sysLocale = myGetLocale(config);
        if (!language.equals("") && !sysLocale.getLanguage().equals(language)) {
            Locale locale = new Locale(language);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                setLocale(config, locale);
            } else {
                setLocaleLegacy(config, locale);
            }
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            context = context.createConfigurationContext(config);
        } else {
            context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }
        return new MyContextWrapper(context);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static Locale getLocaleLegacy(Configuration config){
        return config.locale;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    public static Locale getLocale(Configuration config){
        return config.getLocales().get(0);
    }

    public static Locale myGetLocale(Context context) {
        Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
        return myGetLocale(config);
    }
    public static Locale myGetLocale(Configuration config) {
        Locale sysLocale;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            sysLocale = getLocale(config);
        } else {
            sysLocale = getLocaleLegacy(config);
        }
        return sysLocale;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void setLocaleLegacy(Configuration config, Locale locale){
        config.locale = locale;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    public static void setLocale(Configuration config, Locale locale){
        config.setLocale(locale);
    }
}
```

This all works fine for any other language (and there are several in my app), and even for Turkish the layout id of other equivalent layouts are returned just fine... it's just one layout, and just for Turkish.

I'm stumped.

Comment: I have a (weak) theory, but it depends on the actual value of the layout name and the actual value of your package name. Can you provide those?

Comment: @BenP. Curious what you're thinking.  Turkish "i" problem?  That's always my thought when something fails just turkish.

Comment: Yep, turkish dotted i was my first thought. But I'm willing to believe it's some other glyph too.

Comment: Hmm, you may be onto something... there's a bit of a pattern but not completely... the layout concerned is `layout_header_ınformation` but I now discover it also fails for `layout_app_info`.  However, it is fine for `layout_indices_bar` and `layout_time_settings`.  not sure if it is relevant, but I determined the layout name based on a "tag" with `String layoutName = "layout_" + tag.replaceAll("([A-Z])", "_$1").toLowerCase()` so that `layout_header_ınformation` comes from a tag `headerInformation`.

Comment: So it may be a conversion of a capital "`I`" like in `headerInformation` to `layout_header_ınformation`, but it's OK when converting from `indicesBar` to `layout_indices_bar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In comments you said `String layoutName = "layout_" + tag.replaceAll("([A-Z])", "_$1").toLowerCase()`. You should know that `toLowerCase()` and `toUpperCase()` will do "weird" things with the `i` character in Turkish. I am 99% sure this is the root of the problem.

You can solve by passing a `Locale` argument to the `toLowerCase()` calls... probably want `Locale.ROOT` here.

Comment: Sounds promising... I am just off out but will try this later today.

Comment: Actually I couldn't wait... tried it and *it works*... thank you so much!

Comment: Why `Locale.ROOT` out of interest?

Comment: `Locale.ROOT` is as close as you can get to a "generic" or "vanilla" locale. It has no special rules whatsoever, and this stupidity is valuable when you're manipulating _code_ as opposed to real human _language_.